# trace haskell list comprehension?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

Is there any easy way to trace the evaluation of a List-comprehension in Haskell?
They are nicely compact, but that can also make them difficult to debug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use `Debug.trace`. Something like this:

```
[trace ("comprehending " ++ show x) (x + 1) | x <- [1..10]]
```

Comment: a.k.a. `unsafePerformPrintfDebugging`. Ah, memories of youth, when sticking `printf` into C programs in random places seemed like a perfectly reasonable approach.

Comment: It's ugly, and one doesn't want to become overly reliant on it, but sometimes a little debugging output is just what the doctor ordered.

Comment: True enough. I usually find that `trace` is most useful for debugging situations that I shouldn't have gotten myself into in the first place, but that doesn't mean I won't use it when I do!

Answer (score 6):

List comprehension is rather concise, and usually easy to comprehend.  If you are confused why a particular element doesn't show up in the result you should be able to test it by hand.  Same thing if a element is showing up that you don't expect.  I've never needed any more debugging than GHCi, but if that answer doesn't satisfy you...

List comprehension is just a short-hand for the List monad.  If you expand the list comprehension into `do` notation and add explicit `trace` statements (or use the GHCi debugger`) you should quickly be able to discover what is wrong.